# How do I convert @Html.TextBoxFor to @Html.DropDownList?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view that uses textboxes for input. I need to swap out the textboxes and use dropdownlists. There's only three and I'd like to handcraft this instead of codegen'ing and re-applying any tweaks.

I made the database changes.I changed the field to an int for the FK instead of varchar(50).

I updated the EF data model and confirmed the FKs are mapped correctly.

I changed the markup in the view. I copied the code for this dropdownlist from elsewhere in this app.

```
    <div class="LabelAndField">
        <div class="editor-label-score">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FootLateralDominanceLateralityId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field-score">
            @Html.DropDownList("LateralDominanceLaterality", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FootLateralDominanceLateralityId)
        </div>
    </div>
```

I added the following code to the viewmodel:

```
public virtual LateralDominanceLaterality LateralDominanceLaterality { get; set; }
public virtual LateralDominanceLaterality LateralDominanceLaterality1 { get; set; }
public virtual LateralDominanceLaterality LateralDominanceLaterality2 { get; set; }
```

When I run the application and navigate to this view, I get the following exception:

```
There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'LateralDominanceLaterality'.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you have an DataSource (List<T>, T[], etc..) to fill the DropDownList?

Comment: The error message seems clear. The framework is looking for a property named `LateralDominanceLaterality` of type `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. However it found the property of type: `LateralDominanceLaterality`. May this be an extension method and you are missing the using in this view?

Comment: I guess I need a data source :-D I resolved the issue by adding this code `this.ViewBag.LateralDominanceLaterality = new SelectList(this.db.LateralDominanceLateralities.Where(x => x.IsActive == true), "id", "Name");` to the action on the controller. Everything else was in place.

Comment: How do I avoid using the viewbag to pass the list of options?

Answer (score 1):

It is missing the datasource you have not passed to the DropDownList. The DropDownList on [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) works with a class called `SelectList` where you can pass any implementaion of the `IEnumerable` to it and the properties' name of the Value and Text you want to bind on this control. Try something like this:

1) On the controller set a key on the ViewBag with the name of your property

```
var list = /* build an List you want to show, for sample: List<LateralDominanceLaterality> */;

// create a SelectList to fill the combo with the sintax of the .ctor (list, value property, text property), e.g.:
var items = new SelectList(list, "Id", "Description");

// set on the ViewBag
ViewBag.LateralDominanceLaterality = items;
```

2) On the View, you could just do something like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LateralDominanceLaterality, ViewBag.LateralDominanceLaterality)
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though now it is 3, it may be increased in the future. So don't hard-code 3 items by adding 3 properties to the view model. What you should do is to keep a collection in your viewmodel to have n number of items in that as needed.

Also try to avoid dynamic stuff like ViewBag and ViewData: use a strongly typed approach. So let's change your viewmodel like this:

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
  //Your other existing properties of the viewmodel  goes here

  public List<SelectListItem> Lateralities { set;get;}
  public int SelectedLaterality { set;get;}
 
  public CustomerViewModel()
  {
    Lateralities =new List<SelectListItem>();
  }
}
```

Now in your GET Action method, Set the items for the `Lateralities` collection and send the viewmodel object to our view.

```
public ActionResult Add()
{
   var vm=new CustomerViewModel();
   
 //The below is hard code for adding 3 items to the collection. 
 //You may replace it with data from your table/data access layer

   vm.Lateralities.Add(new SelectListItem { Value="1", Text="Item 1"});
   vm.Lateralities.Add(new SelectListItem { Value="2", Text="Item 2"});
   vm.Lateralities.Add(new SelectListItem { Value="3", Text="Item 3"});

   return View(vm);
}
```

and in our view which is strongly typed to `CustomerViewmodel`, use `Html.DropDownListFor` helper method

```
@model CustomerViewModel
@using(Html.Beginform())
{
  @Html.DropdownListFor(x=>x.SelectedLaterality,
                   new SelectList(Model.Lateralities,"Value","Text"),"select")
  <input type="submit" />    
}
```

When your form is posted, the selected items id will be in the `SelectedLaterality` property of CustomerViewModel.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(CustomerViewModel model)
{
  // check model.SelectedLaterality
  //to do : Save and redirect.
}
```